# Function with nested for loops and accumulator pattern

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

My assignment for class is to create a function that calculates a total jackpot based on the number of players contributing to it on a per round basis.  Each time a round expires a player is eliminated and the game is over when only one player remains.

I'm not sure why my code is not producing the required output.

```
def poker_jackpot(num_players,avg_bet):
    """fuction to calculate jackpot"""
    total_bet=0 #Accumulator used to total the jackpot from avg_bet
    for i in range(avg_bet):
        total_bet=total_bet+avg_bet
    return total_bet #Returning the total for use in the final output

    for i in range(num_players,1,-1): #Range function that counts down the players as each round ends
        print("Total jackpot after" , str(i), "rounds:"+"$",str(total_bet))

poker_jackpot(10,5)
```

Comment: What are the expected and the current outputs?

Comment: The out put is supposed to read “Total jackpot after x rounds is the x

Comment: instead of having `return total_bet`in the middle of your function try putting it at the end

Comment: Currently I am getting nothing back or a long string volt values that isn’t accumulating as it should.

Comment: @Fozoro so put the return value just above the print statement?  Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @Cbeck give me a sec I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried solving your problem using a rather different approach. Here is the script:

```
def poker_jackpot(num_players,avg_bet):
    """fuction to calculate jackpot"""
    total_bet=0 #Accumulator used to total the jackpot from avg_bet
    rounds = 1
    while num_players > 0:      
        total_bet += num_players * avg_bet 
        print("Total jackpot after {} rounds: {} $".format(rounds, str(total_bet)))
        num_players -= 1
        rounds += 1
    return total_bet #Returning the total for use in the final output


poker_jackpot(10,5)
```

I think that you will understand more or less everything in this funcion except probably the `print("Total jackpot after {} rounds: {} $".format(rounds, str(total_bet)))`module which basically a neater alternative to writting `print("Total jackpot after" , str(i), "rounds:"+"$",str(total_bet))`(PS: when you are trying to insert multiple variables into a string I would suggest using `.format()`)

Answer (score 0):

You should put `return total_bet`at the end of your function. so your code will look something like this:

```
def poker_jackpot(num_players,avg_bet):
    """fuction to calculate jackpot"""
    total_bet=0 #Accumulator used to total the jackpot from avg_bet
    for i in range(avg_bet):
        total_bet += total_bet+avg_bet

    for i in range(num_players,1,-1): #Range function that counts down the players as each round ends
        print("Total jackpot after" , str(i), "rounds:"+"$",str(total_bet))
    return total_bet #Returning the total for use in the final output

poker_jackpot(10,5)
```

Comment: Thanks again.  I don’t know if I’d have ever thought to do that.   My accumulator for some reason isn’t calculating but this definitely gets me on my way.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Cbeck no worries! Remember to always put return at the end. Could you please give me more insight on what isn’t working properly?

Comment: I will!  That has been giving me a headache for a while now!  In my final output I’m not getting an accumulating value.  In each iteration it repeats the same number and is does not increase

Comment: @Cbeck Oh I see, I have updated my answer so it should work now. The problem relies in the fact that instead of adding `total_bet + avg_bet` to the total_bet variable, you where just constantly equating it to the value of `total_bet + avg_bet` I fixed this by replacing `total_bet = total_bet+avg_bet`with `total_bet += total_bet+avg_bet`

Comment: @Cbeck did replacing `=` with `+=` work? I am happy to help :)

Comment: I’m still getting a repeating value.

Comment: @Cbeck could you please tell me what is your desirable output, to be honest I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What I am getting is Total jackpot after 10 rounds:$ 6
Total jackpot after 9 rounds:$ 25
Total jackpot after 8 rounds:$ 25
...

Comment: The value of the jackpot is supposed to be rising with the rounds that are being played. So my final output should print the total of the jackpot.  Everything is correct, I just don't understand why my value stays the same and isn't rising with the rounds played.  The out put should display that after 1 round with 10 players betting $5 that the jackpot value is $50 .  After 2 rounds the value should then be 95 instead of $50.  Each round a player drops out and a new total jackpot is created.  I hope this make sense...

Comment: @Cbeck oh so bassical first round: 10*5, second round: (10*5) + 9*5, third round: [(10*5) + 9*5] + 8*5 etc...

Comment: @Cbeck the average bet is always the same, it is just the number of players which are decreasing right ?

Comment: @Cbeck I have submitted another answer hopefully this is what you wanted

Comment: That is perfect.  Thank you so much for your time and effort!  I new to this and the assistance I have found here has extremely helpful to me

Comment: @Cbeck no problem I am happy we got this working, did you understand all the changes I have made?